# Blender 2.9 Merging armatures distorts scale

Tags: armature

I have a character object, and I need to merge the face rig with the body rig
(1 armature is a must for now), however when I join the two rigs together my character's tongue object scales up a lot. How can I fix this? The two rigs are already weight painted.

Comment: You need to apply transformations, basically. If the object transformations are all zeroed, chances are one of the armatures is posed. You can apply a pose as a rest pose by first applying the armature modifier, doing the apply pose in pose mode, then recreating the modifier.

Comment: When I apply all transforms on the face rig the face rig moves up, really confused why.

Comment: Umm, hmm. This delves into what may be much easier to answer with a blend file.

Comment: I selected the children objects of the face rig with Shift G, and then cleared the parent with Alt P, that seemed to fix it

Comment: Oh. Okay, great! GBWY.

Comment: thanks for your help